# Injecting JNDI datasources for JUnit Tests

Tags: java, junit, junit4

I found this example how to Inject JNDI data source in JUnit https://blogs.oracle.com/randystuph/entry/injecting_jndi_datasources_for_junit

I tried this:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;

public class KnowledgebaseTest
{

    public KnowledgebaseTest()
    {
    }

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpClass() throws Exception
    {
        // rcarver - setup the jndi context and the datasource
        try
        {
            // Create initial context
            System.setProperty(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,
                "org.apache.naming.java.javaURLContextFactory");
            System.setProperty(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES,
                "org.apache.naming");
            InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();

            ic.createSubcontext("java:");
            ic.createSubcontext("java:/comp");
            ic.createSubcontext("java:/comp/env");
            ic.createSubcontext("java:/comp/env/jdbc");

            String host = "localhost";
            int port = 5432;
            String dbName = "defaulDB";
            String username = "admin";
            String password = "qwerty";

            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
            Connection conn = null;
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://" + host + ":" + port + "/" + dbName, username, password);
            conn.close();

            ic.bind("jdbc/DefaultDB", conn);

        }
        catch (NamingException ex)
        {
            Logger.getLogger(KnowledgebaseTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDownClass()
    {
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp()
    {
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown()
    {
    }

    @Resource(name = "jdbc/DefaultDB")
    DataSource ds;

    @Test
    public void testPageFirst() throws SQLException
    {
        if (ds == null)
        {
            throw new SQLException("Can't get data source");
        }
        Connection conn = ds.getConnection();

        if (conn == null)
        {
            throw new SQLException("Can't get database connection");
        }

        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        boolean committed = false;
        try
        {
            conn.setAutoCommit(false);
            ps = conn.prepareStatement("UPDATE ACCOUNT SET LAST_LOGIN = CURRENT_DATE WHERE USER_NAME = ?");

            ps.setString(1, "TIMESTAMP");
            ps.executeUpdate();
            ps.close();

            conn.commit();
            committed = true;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (!committed)
            {
                conn.rollback();
            }

            if (ps != null)
            {
                ps.close();
            }
            conn.close();
        }
    }
}
```

But I get this error:

```
javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Cannot instantiate class: org.apache.naming.java.javaURLContextFactory [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.naming.java.javaURLContextFactory]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.naming.java.javaURLContextFactory
```

Can you give me some idea how I can fix this?

Comment: Why would anyone connect to database in order to write UNIT test?

Comment: How do you test business logic?

Comment: By mocking Repository/DAO method calls.

Comment: Testing interaction with database is a subject of integration tests.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot instantiate class: org.apache.naming.java.javaURLContextFactory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14961815/cannot-instantiate-class-org-apache-naming-java-javaurlcontextfactory)